# How to solve "expected an identifier" error in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I'm having a problem with a kernel in CUDA C programming when compiling line 5. I got an `"expected an identifier"` error. Why is this happening?

My kernel function is the following:

```
__global__ void txz_kernel(float *txz,float *vz)
{
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x; --> error
txz[offset]=txz[offset]+vz[offset];
}
```

here is the full code :

```
#include  "../common/book.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "../common/book.h"
#include <fstream>
#define DIMX 320
#define DIMZ 320
#define PI 3.1415926535897932f

__global__ void txz_kernel(float *txz,float *vz)
{
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x; --> error
txz[offset]=txz[offset]+vz[offset];
}

int  main( void ) {
    float              *txz;
    float              *vz;

        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&txz, DIMX * DIMZ * sizeof(float)));
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&vz, DIMX * DIMZ * sizeof(float)));

        float *tempvz = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ));    
        float *temptxz = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ)); 

    for (int i=0; i<DIMX; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<DIMZ; j++) {
        int ij=DIMX*j + i; 
        tempvz[ij]=200.0;
        temptxz[ij]=100.0;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<DIMX; i++) {
        for (int j=(121); j<DIMZ; j++) {
        int ij=DIMX*j + i;       
        tempvz[ij]=250.0;
        temptxz[ij]=150.0;
        }
    }
            HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( vz, tempvz,sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
            HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( txz, temptxz,sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
                dim3    blocks(DIMX/16,DIMZ/16);
                dim3    threads(16,16);
            txz_kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(txz,vz) ;            
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with cuda, but are `threadIdx`, `blockIdx` and `blockDim`, global variables?  What is right before the function prototype?

Comment: Where is the error ocurring? I suggest you to show more code so that anyone could reproduce this...

Comment: Why make us search, please give the line #.

Comment: Did you compile that file with the cuda compiler?

Comment: You must put this code into a file with a `.cu` file extension and compile it with nvcc. There is nothing wrong with the code, it is just that you are not compiling it correctly.

Comment: @KiaMorot Im sorry, someone edited my question, the error occur when compiling the line "int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;"

Comment: @KiaMorot: It is a bit hypocritical to be complaining about not being told where the error was when it was **you** that edited that precise piece of information out of the question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code , I have just compiled it by myself

Comment: úŰ
óŰ
űűű7747447űű74üúű7

Comment: @TripleS really? maybe it's my library setting or something? thank you anyway

Comment: @talonmies comment should be posted as an answer, as it is undoubtedly  correct.

Comment: Also, a little-known alternative to placing the code in a .cu file is to put it in a file with another extension and pass the `-x cu` option to `nvcc`.

Answer (score 4):

You must put this code into a file with a .cu file extension and compile it with nvcc. nvcc uses the file extension to determine the compilation trajectory of any given input file, and if the file doesn't have a .cu file extension, it assumes there is no device code in the input and passes it through to the host compiler. There is nothing wrong with the code, it is just that you are not compiling it correctly.

Let's start with your kernel code in a `.cpp` file:

```
> type txzkernel.cpp
__global__ void txz_kernel(float *txz, float *vz)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    txz[offset]=txz[offset]+vz[offset];
}
```

Now let's try compiling it with nvcc:

```
> nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" -c txzkernel.cpp
txzkernel.cpp
txzkernel.cpp(1) : error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
txzkernel.cpp(1) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
does not support default-int
txzkernel.cpp(3) : error C2065: 'threadIdx' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(3) : error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(3) : error C2065: 'blockIdx' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(3) : error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(3) : error C2065: 'blockDim' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(3) : error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(4) : error C2065: 'threadIdx' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(4) : error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(4) : error C2065: 'blockIdx' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(4) : error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(4) : error C2065: 'blockDim' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(4) : error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'blockDim' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(5) : error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
txzkernel.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'gridDim' : undeclared identifier
txzkernel.cpp(5) : error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
```

The result is a lot of syntax errors because the host compiler (Microsoft Visual C++ in this case) doesn't understand any of the CUDA language extensions in the kernel code.

Now rename the file so it has the correct extension and compile again:

```
> rename txzkernel.cpp txzkernel.cu
> nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" -c txzkernel.cu
txzkernel.cu
tmpxft_000012dc_00000000-3_txzkernel.cudafe1.gpu
tmpxft_000012dc_00000000-8_txzkernel.cudafe2.gpu
txzkernel.cu
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z10txz_kernelPfS_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z10txz_kernelPfS_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0]
tmpxft_000012dc_00000000-3_txzkernel.cudafe1.cpp
tmpxft_000012dc_00000000-14_txzkernel.ii
```

No errors. If you use nvcc to compile the kernel code and you put the kernel code into a file with the appropriate extension, then this code will compile without modification.

Comment: What is the version of you nvcc and what is your compilation environment? I can reproduce @Leon's error information with nvcc V8.0.44 under Archlinux; the compilation command I was using is `nvcc -Xptxas="-V" -c z2.cu -x cu`